# Simple rebus, don't scold me

Tags: rebus

[image]

These are internet Tabs.

Hint :

> Simple rebus, don't scold me in slang words.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Seems like there might be more to it, but I'm seeing:

> The acronym "WTF".  W: WhatsApp, T: Twitter, F: Facebook

I guess the title makes sense because:

> If you're upset with someone, you might "scold" them by asking them WTF???

Answer (score 3):

Thinking of the title "don't scold me" I think it might be

> [Don't kill the messenger](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shooting_the_messenger)

Reasoning

> WhatsApp is also known as WhatsApp **Messenger** and by keeping the tab open you are not "killing" it.

What's not quite clear

> I'm unsure about the Twitter and Facebook tabs but perhaps OP is suggesting that both of these platforms have similar messaging functionality which could threaten WhatsApp, encouraging the idea of not killing WhatsApp Messenger in favour of either of these.

If not for the title, my first thought was

> Social media keeping tabs on you.

Comment: Keeping with that theme, Twitter and Facebook both provide the same functionality, so it's not far-fetched to assume those tabs have that functionality active.

Answer (score 3):

Mentally, this is screaming:

> What's up home boy?!
>  WhatsApp: What's Up
>  Home / Twitter: Home
>  Facebook: ?

However, I can't relate the last tab to the final word so I'm still looking.

---

<sub>*I'll update my answer if I come to a revelation or think of something else.*</sub>